# NVarChar to C# Data Types

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

The database stores nvarchar, I retrieve the information and I'd like to jam it into C# data types without any declarative conversion code.

Can you implicitly convert nvarchar to C# data types? (e.g. nvarchar to int)

Comment: You can *parse* character data into numeric types, using something like `int.TryParse()`.  Just be aware that there's no *implicit* guarantee that any given string will be interpretable as numeric, so your code should handle conditions where parsing fails.

Comment: @David See my edit above.

Comment: There's no mechanism in the language which will pretend that a string is an integer, no.  Such a mechanism would be inherently error-prone since not all strings can be interpreted as integers.  You can *write* such a mechanism, which would internally performs the safety checks on the data before trying to convert it.  Though your best bet is probably to store numeric data as, well, numeric data.

Comment: This is part of a potential EAV system I'm looking at that doesn't currently give a way to store anything but nvarchar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nvarchar is a string, if you want to turn it in to a `int` you will have to go through some kind of conversion as I could have "Potato" in the column, what `int` would that map to?

[Here is a listing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) of all of the SQL types and what C# types they map to. So if you want an `int` in C# without conversion your only option is an `int` in Sql.

Answer (score 1):

Not much you can do with it implicitly, other than treating it as a string.

You could use some logic to `Parse` or better `TryParse` it if you expect it to be an int.

Have a look at the following

```
string nvarchar1 = "12";
string nvarchar2 = "1.2";
string nvarchar3 = "hello"; 

var one = int.Parse(nvarchar1); // good 
var two = int.Parse(nvarchar2); // exception
var three = int.Parse(nvarchar3); // exception  

var bone = int.TryParse(nvarchar1,out one); // true
var btwo = int.TryParse(nvarchar2,out one).Dump(); // False, 0
var bthree = int.TryParse(nvarchar3,out one); // False, 0
```

It all depends on if and how much you trust your input in your database.

Comment: Great answer. TryParse() with bool return value is a great function.